# Unable to match the entire Cyrillic alphabet using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to return all cyrillic words from this sentence:

```
"I like to eat healthy food with a little bit of pepper. Cанкт-Петербу́рг э́то оди́н из са́мых краси́вых городо́в Росси́и.Он был осно́ван импера́тором Петро́м I(пе́рвым).Импера́тор реши́л постро́ить го́род здесь, что́бы откры́ть для Росси́и «окно́ в Евро́пу. La Navidad dura dos semanas y las fiestas más importantes son Nochebuena, Navidad, Nochevieja y Reyes. En las casas se pone el tradicional belén, una maqueta con figuras que representa el nacimiento de Jesús, y un gran árbol donde se colocan los regalos";
```

I tried to use `/\p{sc=Cyrillic}\w+/giu` to return all cyrillic words but it's returning **null** instead; Then I tried `/(?<=[\u0400- \u4FF]+\w+)/giu` because this range is the Cyrillic alphabet. I've used 7 different RegExp websites but none of them seem to support **\p** class.
What's wrong?

Comment: Try: /\p{sc=Cyrillic}+/ This returns cyrillic words while \w+ only returns acii words.

Comment: Btw: Which browser do you use, not all browsers support unicode.

Comment: Firefox, Brave and Google Chrome.

Comment: There's another problem: it's returning most of the letter but not all. The letter **C** for example, it's in the alphabet but my guess is that my RegExp thinks **C** is ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not unicode if you use `\u0400`. So remove the modifier `u`.

The class with all allowed characters works quite fine, see https://regex101.com/r/PE4fQT/1

There are 2 different C and с.